# What does $d/dx$ actually mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm starting to learn about differential equations, and I'm having trouble mentally adjusting to working with differentials as separate quantities. (I took calculus in high school and college but I don't remember ever learning about differentials or differential equations, so the whole concept is refusing to stick in my brain.)

Mechanically I can do the work and get the right answer. But I don't really understand why it's correct to do the operations that I'm doing. My problem is that I can't quite grasp why it's OK to do arithmetic on differentials just because Leibniz's notation happens to make it "look right". I mostly get (at least, I can accept) why we can take a DE like this:

$dy/dx = -xy$

and multiply through by $dx$, divide by $y$, then anti-differentiate the resulting two parts. I have always thought that $dy/dx$ was just a different form of notation for a function, $f'(x)$ that described the rate of change of y vs. x. But I can accept that it's actually a ratio of two infinitesimal numeric values.

Where my understanding fails is with this form of the same differential equation:

$(d/dx + x)y = 0$

at which point we "distributed" the $y$ to get the subsequent step. But I have no idea what $d/dx$ actually means. In my mind, I have treated it as an operation applied to functions: you "apply" $d/dx$ to a function written in terms of $x$ to get it's derivative. How, then can we add to and multiply by an operation? To me, that second equation looks exactly as if you had written $(! + x)y = 0$ and expanded that to $y! = -xy$, which obviously makes no sense. Why then, does it "work" for $d/dx$? What numeric quantity is $d/dx$ supposed to be?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20685/in-differential-calculus-why-is-dy-dx-written-as-d-dx-y

Comment: @JonasMeyer thanks, that looks like interesting information; but I got lost by sentence three of the answer :) I assume that stuff is from linear algebra (next on my list)?

Comment: Technically, it just notation for a specific limit, or, later, a linear function on a function space.

Comment: This has been asked here before, and great answers were given.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I've read lots of questions/answers that talk about $d/dx$ and all of them reinforce my intuition that it's an operator, not a numeric value you can do arithmetic on...

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield OK...?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff so if my question has been asked and answered on here before I cannot find it, so I would appreciate any pointers...

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I was thinking about [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-dy-dx-not-a-ratio) but now I realize the question is different so I apologize. You can think of it as a linear operator in some sense. I recommend you take a look at Spiegel's "Applied Differential Equations", specially the section 4.6 called "Abbreviated Methods Involving Operators".

Comment: To give a suggestive example, consider the differential equation $y''-y'+y=x^3-3x^2+1$. We can write this as $(D^2-D+1)y=x^3-3x^2+1$. But $$\frac{1}{1-D+D^2}=1+D-D^3-D^4+\cdots$$ whence $y=1(x^3-3x^2+1)+D(x^3-3x^2+1)-D^3(x^3-3x^2+1)-D^4(\cdots)$ but the fourth derivative already vanishes so we get $y=x^3-6x-5$. Some details must be not forgetten. For example, $D$ doesn't commute with functions in the sense $D(fg)\neq fDg$ say.

Comment: To only touch on one aspect of your question, let me point out that $d/dx+x$ *does* make a lot of sense when $d/dx$ is thought of as an operator, if you also see $x$ as an operator ('*operation*,' as you call it): it's *multiplication by* $x$. You will see this in Linear Algebra, too, where one frequently encounters expressions of the form $(A-\lambda I)x=0$. Here, $A$ is a matrix but $\lambda$ is a scalar ('*numeric value*'); to add them up, one employs the identity matrix $I$ (same dimension as $A$). In your ODE example, $x$ is implicitly multiplied by the *identity operator* - that's all.